# Update parent table, based on one record from children table (one-to-many)

Tags: mariadb, update

I have a `Persons` table, which has a `DefaultEamil` column.

I also have an `Emails` table which has `PersonId, Value, IsDefault` columns. A person can not have multiple default emails. There is an index constraint on it.

For the sake of performance and easier filtering, I want to update the `Persons` table and set the `DefaultEmail` to the `Value` of the default email.

This is what I wrote:

```
update Persons
set DefaultEmail = 
(
    select Value
    from Emails
    where IsDefault = true
    and PersonId = Persons.Id
)
```

It executes but reports that only 0 rows are updated.

What could be wrong?

I'm using:

> MySQL version: 11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 through PHP extension MySQLi

**Update**:

I also tried the following query, but again it reports 0 rows:

```
update Persons p
left join
(
    select PersonId, Value
    from Emails
    where IsDefault = true
) as e
on p.Id = e.PersonId
set p.DefaultEmail = e.Value
```

Comment: Not related to your  specific question , but why there are a lot of  not accepted answers on your previous questions ?  As per the given question, please add some data example and expected result in text format. Would be much better if you reproduce your issue on  [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT)

Comment: @ErgestBasha simply because we did not get workable answers. Yet I marked them as accepted answers if that makes you happy.

Comment: @ErgestBasha, I'll try to create that. But I asked it since these queries seem to be totally OK. I just thought maybe I have not understood something fundamental about how to write queries.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/twsOmUBR). Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: How many rows does `SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE IsDefault = true` return? How about the query `SELECT * FROM Persons p INNER JOIN Emails e on p.Id = e.PersonId`?